# Parse data using JSOUP for android app

Tags: java, android

I'm having issues parsing tags using JSOUP for android. I keep trying to go down further in the document the app doesn't work. Please help. I got "TR" to work which will parse all data within a TR, but I want to grab a single element and parse to the toast box.

Thank you

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class JsoupTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button myButton;
    myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://money.cnn.com/data/bonds/").get();
                Elements divs = doc.select("td.login.div.status");
                for (Element div : divs) {                      
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), div.text(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Like this, remove the `.` in selector

```
Elements divs = doc.select("td.login div.status");
```

Due to current source:

```
<td class="login">
    <div class="brdr_left">
    &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="username" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="status">
```

`td` is an `Element` having `class: login` -> selector: `td.login`

`div` is an `Element` having `class: status` -> selector: `div.status`

also, `td` is ancestor of the child `div`

so the final selector: `td.login div.status`